# What's the most efficient way to add geom_segment to a scatter plot in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have data whose points and geom_segments need to be the same color as determined by year.  I have the desired plot of everything except the geom_segments.

[image]

What's the most efficient way to add geom_segment to a scatter plot in ggplot with existing points which are of the same color as the points? I seek line segments that are connected within each year but not connected across years. That is, I desire 3 different colored connected line segments for each year that are not connected across years.  This Excel graph is somewhat similar to what I want though the data is different and there are no points plotted.

[image]

I attempted the use of the code at
https://r-graph-gallery.com/connected_scatterplot_ggplot2.html which does not produce the desired result.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)

set.seed(100)
tibble_tabble <- tibble(Year = c( rep(2020,12), rep(2021,12), rep(2022,12) ),
                        X    = runif(36),
                        Y    = sample(101:136, 36)
                        )


p <- ggplot( tibble_tabble , aes(x = X , y = Y ) ) +          
  geom_point( aes(color = factor(Year)) , size = 2 , alpha = 0.7) +
#  geom_segment(aes( color = factor(Year)),
#                   xend = c(tail(x, n =-1), NA), 
#                   yend = c(tail(y, n =-1), NA)
#  ) +
  scale_color_discrete( name="" )    

  

ggplotly( p )
```

Comment: Try `geom_path` instead of `geom_segment`

Comment: geom_path( aes( color = factor(Year)) ) works!  Thank you.